# WebApp: How and where to handle an expired authorization with 'back to login'

Tags: architecture, authentication

**Situation**
I have a Single page web app with REST API. When the user logs in, they receive an authorization token. The token which will expire after some time.

When the user tries to make a server request, but the authorization token is already expired, I want the user to be forwarded to the login screen.

**Current Approach**
Whenever a server-request is made, within the request function, I check for token validity. If the token is expired, I relocate the window using `window.location`, to bring the user back to the main screen.

*Why this smells bad*

- A request function should only do a request and not check for token validity(?).
- The request function has dependency to `window` and the token storage location.
- A request function should not call upon `window`.

### Question

How would a *good* architecture for this problem look like?
I.e. How and where would I implement the token check and window forwarding?

### Another approach

I've been thinking, if this architecture is a *good* one to solve this problem in a clean way. (*Backend* describes the object communicating with the backend server. It's not the backend server itself)
[image]

Arrows are showing data/object/callback flow.

Comment: How does your client code handle a 401 Unauthorized response? This should likely share the code paths for token expiration. The client doesn't have to check for token expiration, but it may be useful as a convenience. Your callback solution sounds like it elegantly achieves the desired decoupling, if you want to handle the errors on that layer (which can be quite sensible). Many use cases are well suited for long-lived tokens though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! In regard of token expiration, the client code does not handle 401. It checks locally for token expiration beforehand. Could you please elaborate on "Many use cases are well suited for long-lived tokens though"? I can't follow what you mean.

Comment: Regarding expiration: my bank logs me out after 5 minutes of inactivity. That's reasonable in this context since there's a lot at stake. Automated log-out can also be appropriate in other high-risk contexts such as admin panels. But for many use cases, expiring tokens would be a pure annoyance. Many websites such as Stack Exchange expire session cookies after 6 or 12 months, which is basically forever in that context.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: You were inferring that the whole expiration-procedure might not be necessary at all (depending on the/my actual use case).

Comment: Correct, limiting validity periods of tokens is a security measure that is more appropriate in some contexts than others. It absolutely is a “best practice” for security, but I wanted to prompt you to consider whether writing special expiration-handling logic is even appropriate in your use case. Best practices are guidelines, not laws. But I know nothing about your context, so it's entirely possible that you have created an appropriate design and that my comment is irrelevant.

Comment: I appreciate the concern!